# Automatic Backup in Laravel

Tags: laravel, backup

I am not able to backup laravel automatically. I have tried 
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup but couldn't get the job done

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/617

Any other ways of getting automated laravel backups?

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: @Bart Laravel 5.5.28

Comment: and package version of laravel-backup? Are you sure you could not just add a cron job with `php artisan schedule:run`?

Comment: @Bart tried  $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily()->at('18:00'); in app\Console\Kernal.php but its not working

Comment: @Bart this is sorted. Was able to sort after referring to many posts